# Custom react hooks infinite recursion, no recusrion break because of Rule of hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, react-hooks, react-query

I've encountered interesting problem with custom react hooks, rule of hooks, and recursion. I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for you time.

I have a custom hook `useServerData(entityIds)`. This hook internaly calls (depends on) other custom hook `useFilters(entityIds)`. This hook cyclickly depends on `useServerData(shorterEntityIds)`. Maybe it seems like a logical defect, but it is just a recurion because shorterEntityIds are strictly shorter array. Without rule of hooks, I would wrote recursion break like:

```js
let filters = [];
if (shorterEntityIds.length > 0) {
    filters = useFilters(shorterEntityIds)
}
```

But it is prohibited by rule of hooks (and I understand why). Without the break JavaScript throws `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

How would you solve this? How to break the cycle? What is a React idiomatic way?

Thank you.

**EDIT**: As Bergi requested I'm adding more specific code for this.

```js
// Returns dictionary where key is given filterId and value is QueryResult<FilterRange>
// Where returned FilterRange depends on Filter and prescending Filters for each Filter
export const useFilterRanges = (filterIds) => {
    const filtersById = useFilters(filterIds);
    const prescendingQueryFiltersById = usePrescendingQueryFilters(filterIds);
    const filterRanges = useQueries(filterIds.map((filterId) => {
        const filter = filtersById[filterId];
        const prescendingFilters = prescendingQueryFiltersById[filterId];
        return fetchFilterRange(filter, prescendingFilters);
    }));
    return zipObject(filterIds, filterRanges);
};
```

```js
// Returns dictionary where key is given filterId and value is Array<QueryFilter>
// Where returned Array<QueryFilter> depends on internal state (order of Filters) and QueryFilters
export const usePrescendingQueryFilters = (filterIds) => {
    const allFilterIds = useAllFilterIds();
    const index = findLastIndex(allFilterIds, (filterId) => includes(filterIds, filterId));

    // allPrecendingIds are always at least one item shorter than filterIds
    const allPrecendingIds = take(allFilterIds, index);
    const queryFiltersById = useQueryFilters(allPrecendingIds);
    return chain(filterIds)
        .keyBy()
        .mapValues((filterId) => {
            const index = indexOf(allFilterIds, filterId);
            const precendingIds = take(allFilterIds, index);
            const queryFilters = precendingIds.map((id) => queryFiltersById[id]);
            return queryFilters.flatMap((queryFilter) => queryFilter ?? []);
        })
        .value();
};
```

```js
// Returns dictionary where key is given filterId and value is QueryFilter
// Where returned QueryFilter depends on QueryResult<FilterRange> and Filter
export const useQueryFilters = (filterIds) => {
    const filtersById = useFilters(filterIds);
    const rangesById = useFilterRanges(filterIds);
    return chain(filterIds)
        .keyBy()
        .mapValues((filterId) => {
            const filter = filtersById[filterId];
            const range = rangesById[filterId];
            return constructQueryFilters(filter, range);
        })
        .value(); 
};
```

Note the code is simplified (I've doublechecked but it can contain some typos) and the real project cycle is even bigger, but I believe this is kind of minimal meaningful example. :)

Comment: Please post the full code of both hooks. The general solution is to inject the dependency, but we can't tell you how to do that without knowing what the dependency is.

Comment: I've added meaningful example to the post. Looking forward to see how to inject the dependency. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so I assume that `useFilters` and `useAllFilterIds` is your state the queries should depend on. And now you need to make a dynamic amount of requests, do I understand that correctly? Ultimately, you must call `useQueries` only once.

Comment: Almost correct. prescendingFilters are the cumberstone. They change the request and the response.

Comment: I have read the question several times to see what it's about and I feel like I am missing one important part of it. What is goal here? It looks like a very complex structure that in the end just calls a `useQueries` hook. Are you sure you want to do all the transformations as custom hooks? What if you split it to first have a `useMemo` that can prepare all data recursively inside (so without other hooks) and than you use hooks (`useQueries`) with what is computed by the memo?

Comment: Good point. Goal is to get FilterRange for given filterId. But to be able to fetch it, I need to know the FilterRanges of prescending filters. 

I wanted to use recursion. But because of hooks it is not possible. 

I can't prepare data in useMemo, because they are also fetched asynchronously.